# Put Access backend database in protected map

Tags: ms-access, frontend, backend

I have a split Access database with a front-end and a back-end. I would like to know if users of the front-end can use the application while the back-end is placed inside a protected map, where they don't have access to.

The back-end only exists out of tables. These tables are linked in the front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the back-end is an Access db, of course not. But you could have tried that easily.
On the other end, why using a mapped drive ? You can link to a UNC.
Ultimately you could also use SQL Server as a back-end. That will give you more performance and security.

Comment: I have edited my question. When I search the internet I get the feeling it should be possible when the back-end is only linked tables. I can't test this myself because I don't have access to this map myself yet. You still think it's not possible in this case?

Comment: @DennisvdEijnde  Back-end is normally ALWAYS made of tables only

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO. The font-end basically has the user's access rights and needs to access the back-end. So, the user must have access to the back-end.

You can [password-protect](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Encrypt-a-database-by-using-a-database-password-fe1cc5fe-f9a5-4784-b090-fdb2673457ab) an Access database.